# What does Firefox send for HTML5 GeoLocation data in its request?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, ip-geolocation

If I have a computer connected to a router which has a wireless access point and the computer is connected by a cable, does Firefox use the ip address of the connection or the MAC address of the access point to send to the GeoLocation service when using HTML5 GeoLocation API?

It seems a MAC address would be more accurate for location determination.

I used FireFox to go to http://html5demos.com/geo and a network sniffer to find out what FF is sending for network identification but I couldn't find the relevant data. Any ideas which request has it? In the URL or form data?

**Addition:**

Can the answer include the actual request, as captured by network sniffer, sent by Firefox? I know Firefox sends either an ip address or MAC address but I am not seeing any kind of identification being sent out.

Comment: It doesn't need to 'send' an IP address, the IP address is implicit in the request (otherwise the server wouldn't know where to send the response to)

Answer (score 1):

In this HTML5 example, your geolocation is never sent to the server, all is done client-side.

geolocation : this javascript gets your exact position, whit latitude/longitude

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function() {console.log(arguments)}, function() {console.log(arguments)});
```

Firefox [use google location services to locate you](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla1.9.1/source/dom/src/geolocation/NetworkGeolocationProvider.js) based on your public IP (router).

Then google maps then display a marker at your position

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng, 
    map: map, 
    title:"You are here!"
});
```

Comment: Why doesn't it send MAC addresses? I read this happens too. Before Firefox knows my location, it has to sending some other kind of information first. There's no GPS attached.

Comment: see this answer : http://superuser.com/questions/77460/html5-precise-geolocation . The location is detected based on many factors : gps, ip, mac...

Answer (score 0):

Firefox actually gathers MAC addresses of surrounding WIFI access points and send them to Google Location Services for them to achieve better location accuracy than GeoIP alone.

Google has been using StreetView cars to gather WIFI AP - location information for a long time.

Comment: I don't see this happening. Do you have a capture example?

Comment: Not exactly, what I am saying is how Firefox works internally (with Google) to provide geolocation services that is more accurate than GeoIP alone. https://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/geolocation/ Look the first question.

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063200/firefoxs-geo-wifi-urls-https-www-google-com-loc-json-not-used/5066688#5066688), it sends a JSON object like this:

```
{"version":"1.1.0","request_address":true}
```

It doesn't send your MAC address.  The [full Geolocation API Network Protocol is documented here](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/geolocation_network_protocol.html).

Comment: What about answers that mention sending out MAC addresses of nearby AP's.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich I tried on a laptop running on WiFi and there were two additional parameters - `access_token` and `wifi_towers` (as per the documentation I linked to).  However the value for `wifi_towers` was an empty array `[]` - the browser would need to be running with root permissions to have access to that information I think.