# Firefox's geo.wifi.url's https://www.google.com/loc/json not used?

Tags: firefox, html, geolocation, packet-sniffers

I used a network sniffer and examined all the requests going out from Firefox when going to http://html5demos.com/geo. According to my Firefox, the geolocation service according to geo.wifi.uri entry is https://www.google.com/loc/json. However I don't see this url in any of the requests.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see it in [LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/):

```
https://www.google.com/loc/json

POST /loc/json HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0b12pre) Gecko/20110220 Firefox/4.0b12pre
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 42
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
    {"version":"1.1.0","request_address":true}

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Mon, 21 Feb 2011 13:34:05 GMT
Expires: Mon, 21 Feb 2011 13:34:05 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 238
Server: GSE
```

Comment: Note that it's an HTTPS request, so your sniffer won't be able to see the HTTP headers in the way that LiveHTTPHeaders can (it intercepts the request before it hits the SSL layer in Firefox).

Answer (score 5):

If your wifi interface is enabled, Firefox sends to Google all the wifi signal strength around you in order to locate you (signals strength,mac addresses and locations of all private and public hotspots were captured by Google with their Street View's cars I guess).
Here is the full POST request captured with [TcpCatcher](http://www.tcpcatcher.org) (and its SSL mode)

POST /loc/json HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Content-Length: 4233
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.119 Safari/534.16
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

{"access_token":"2:fHl0jGoQDeLFKfUn:sn0HJO00jOQV2334","host":"html5demos.com","radio_type":"unknown","request_address":false,"version":"1.1.0","wifi_towers":[{"age":0,"mac_address":"00-13-10-27-ec-ba","signal_strength":-82,"ssid":"linksys"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"00-14-bf-e2-b6-a3","signal_strength":-101,"ssid":"grepre2"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"00-17-33-9e-4d-a8","signal_strength":-94,"ssid":"NEUF_4DA4"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"00-17-33-cc-b5-10","signal_strength":-69,"ssid":"NEUF_B50C"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"00-17-33-cc-b5-11","signal_strength":-66,"ssid":"Neuf WiFi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"00-17-33-cc-b5-12","signal_strength":-69,"ssid":"SFR WiFi Public"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"00-1a-2b-0e-66-74","signal_strength":-86,"ssid":"NUMERICABLE-AB1B"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"00-1f-33-47-c0-50","signal_strength":-80,"ssid":"SUPERMAN"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"00-1f-33-e0-1e-1f","signal_strength":-80,"ssid":"NUMERICABLE-5866"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"00-1f-9f-f4-1f-17","signal_strength":-90,"ssid":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"02-81-31-a2-c4-98","signal_strength":-71,"ssid":"wifi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"02-81-31-a2-c4-99","signal_strength":-69},{"age":0,"mac_address":"02-81-31-a2-c4-9a","signal_strength":-68,"ssid":"FreeWifi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"02-81-31-a2-c4-9b","signal_strength":-69,"ssid":"freephonie"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"06-20-9f-00-3d-24","signal_strength":-82,"ssid":"damiconexion"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"06-20-9f-00-3d-25","signal_strength":-82},{"age":0,"mac_address":"06-20-9f-00-3d-26","signal_strength":-81,"ssid":"FreeWifi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"06-20-9f-00-3d-27","signal_strength":-82,"ssid":"freephonie"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"26-b7-bb-70-e1-d8","signal_strength":-93,"ssid":"DC_baby"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"26-b7-bb-70-e1-d9","signal_strength":-91},{"age":0,"mac_address":"26-b7-bb-70-e1-da","signal_strength":-89,"ssid":"FreeWifi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"26-b7-bb-70-e1-db","signal_strength":-94,"ssid":"freephonie"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"26-f8-5c-ec-bc-a4","signal_strength":-80},{"age":0,"mac_address":"26-f8-5c-ec-bc-a5","signal_strength":-80},{"age":0,"mac_address":"26-f8-5c-ec-bc-a6","signal_strength":-81,"ssid":"FreeWifi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"26-f8-5c-ec-bc-a7","signal_strength":-80,"ssid":"freephonie"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"30-46-9a-43-fc-e5","signal_strength":-84,"ssid":"DartyBox_98DE"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"32-46-9a-43-fc-e6","signal_strength":-84,"ssid":"DartyBox_98DE_WEP"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"4e-0a-94-3d-d6-38","signal_strength":-82,"ssid":"neko"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"4e-0a-94-3d-d6-39","signal_strength":-82},{"age":0,"mac_address":"4e-0a-94-3d-d6-3a","signal_strength":-80,"ssid":"FreeWifi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"4e-0a-94-3d-d6-3b","signal_strength":-82},{"age":0,"mac_address":"5c-33-8e-eb-6c-c0","signal_strength":-87,"ssid":"Livebox-0510"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"72-f5-aa-cd-b7-e4","signal_strength":-86,"ssid":"Kermazeguen"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"72-f5-aa-cd-b7-e5","signal_strength":-87},{"age":0,"mac_address":"72-f5-aa-cd-b7-e6","signal_strength":-87,"ssid":"FreeWifi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"72-f5-aa-cd-b7-e7","signal_strength":-88,"ssid":"freephonie"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"76-a6-a6-5a-90-c8","signal_strength":-78,"ssid":"pipiou_wifi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"76-a6-a6-5a-90-c9","signal_strength":-79},{"age":0,"mac_address":"76-a6-a6-5a-90-ca","signal_strength":-77,"ssid":"FreeWifi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"76-a6-a6-5a-90-cb","signal_strength":-78},{"age":0,"mac_address":"86-9c-8f-a0-ac-e4","signal_strength":-78,"ssid":"touhere"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"86-9c-8f-a0-ac-e5","signal_strength":-82},{"age":0,"mac_address":"86-9c-8f-a0-ac-e6","signal_strength":-83,"ssid":"FreeWifi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"86-9c-8f-a0-ac-e7","signal_strength":-82,"ssid":"freephonie"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"c0-3f-0e-b6-9a-37","signal_strength":-64,"ssid":"NUMERICABLE-825A"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"da-0f-67-af-23-10","signal_strength":-71,"ssid":"freeboxtomseb"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"da-0f-67-af-23-11","signal_strength":-70},{"age":0,"mac_address":"da-0f-67-af-23-12","signal_strength":-71,"ssid":"FreeWifi"},{"age":0,"mac_address":"da-0f-67-af-23-13","signal_strength":-71}]}

Answer (score 0):

google json has stop service.
you can call [minigps]: http://www.minigps.net/map.html "click to query" could use google json api, only change the ip to: http://www.minigps.net/minigps/map/google/location

fllow is the http bytes:

```
 URL:http://www.minigps.net/minigps/map/google/location
 Request Method:POST
 Status Code:200 OK
 Request Headersview source
 Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
 Accept-Charset:GBK,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
 Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
 Connection:keep-alive
 Content-Length:191
 Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
 Cookie:bdshare_firstime=1356366713546; JSESSIONID=68243935CD3355089CF07A3A22AAB372
 Host:www.minigps.net
 Origin:http://www.minigps.net
 Referer:http://www.minigps.net/map.html
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko)            Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4
 X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
 Request Payload
 {"version":"1.1.0","host":"maps.google.com","cell_towers":  [{"cell_id":"3721","location_area_code":"9779","mobile_country_code":"460","mobile_network_c       ode":"0","age":0,"signal_strength":-65}]}
  Response Headersview source
 Content-Type:application/json
 Date:Sat, 12 Jan 2013 06:03:15 GMT
 Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
 Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

Note: I'm affiliated with minigps.net.