# Unable to get accurate results from Browserlocation API with curl

Tags: google-maps, curl, wireshark

I'm trying to get the current location of my computer from Google's BrowserLocation API.

[How to create a script to query Google Browserlocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972546/how-to-create-a-script-to-query-google-browserlocation/30986056): This thread  helped me construct the script, but one problem remains: the accuracy is way off when using curl from the command line: `"accuracy" : 11178`. Bafflingly, if I copy-paste the same address in my browser, the returned JSON is perfectly fine with an accuracy of `"accuracy" : 52`.

What could the crucial difference be, and how do I modify the curl script to work like my browsers do? There is [JSON, CURL and Google's geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433901/json-curl-and-googles-geolocation) this previous thread with what appears to be a similar issue, but the solution posted does not help me.

I have Wireshark, and a capture of the two methods of accessing the API. I am currently trying to figure out how to retrieve the relevant packets for inspection. If anyone can help me with this intermediate step, that would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got it to work. The issue was that I didn't URL escape the names of the access points. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298258/350875) for how to do this with Perl.